# Adding day to MYYYY timestamp

Tags: c#

I have an integer of the month/year. I would like to take that integer and convert it to a `MM/D/YYYY DateTime`. To do so, I am assuming that I would need to add the date in there before I can convert it into a DateTime. Would someone be able to help me out with a clean way to do this?

**EDIT**

I just need to make D the first of the month - so D would be 1.

Also, this would not be creating a new timestamp but an existing one and adding a 1 to it. I would also like to highlight the format of the integer (which is also in the title) MYYYY.  For example, the integer 92005 would need to be converted to 9/1/2005.

Comment: What do you expect D to be? 1?

Comment: @YoryeNathan - yes i do.

Comment: `var dt = new DateTime(years, months, 1)`

Comment: What is the format of your integer ? can you give us an example ?

Comment: @Orace - it is in the title. i will also edit my question to have it included. format is MYYYY

Comment: So 111984 is for 11/01/1984 and 012001 is for 01/01/2001. You may include this kind of example since understanding that is important.

Comment: @Orace - well not exactly... sorry for the confusion, but it would be 92015 which would be for 9/01/2015

Comment: Actually you write the same things as I do. You may know that 092015 and 92015 are equals if we speak about integer. If we speak about strings they are not. You should be clear about it.

Comment: You are right, I read it too quickly and haven't seen dates like 1984 and 2001 in a long time lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) you can complete as follows:

```
var dateTime = new System.DateTime( year,
                                    month, 
                                    1 //default the day to 1st of the month
                                   );
```

---

Assuming the format of MYYYY as per your question title, you can extract the components as follows:

`var year = MYYYY % 10000`

`var month = MYYYY / 10000`

---

Once you have a DateTime object, you can easily convert it to a date string as follows using [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx):

`dateTime.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: Sorry, It is in the title. MYYYY. Also, please see my edit above.

Comment: Yes I noticed your question title after the fact, please see the updated answer.

Comment: just for the record it is only M. So `9` instead of `09`. Will this make a difference?

Comment: It will not make a difference, the math still works out the same.

Comment: I'm not clear on the last edit where you state " this would not be creating a new timestamp but an existing one and adding a 1 to it", if you can clarify on this I will update my answer if / as necessary.  Are you trying to get a formatted string perhaps rather than a DateTime object?

Comment: Try using `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of modulo and division. You can even use `.TryParseExact` for validation.

Comment: @Caramiriel If you refer to the OP, and check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) that would not work as he is starting from an `int` while that method takes `string` argument.

Comment: @VincentUgenti -  thank you for the help! your answer got me where i needed to be!